# How to understand the sequential characterization of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying Real Analysis and struggle a lot on how to interrupt the definitions. I'm on the sequential characterization of continuity and cannot comprehend what the statement in my textbook actually means. I am posting a photo because I'm still unfamiliar with how to write limits on math stack

[image]

Could someone offer a worded interpretation on what this definition is trying to tell me? What properties it is representing? I also need to prove the sequential characterization of continuity but first thing is understanding what the definition is trying to tell me.

Comment: There is a typo and the 2nd to last $x_k$ should not be present. Maybe this is what is causing trouble for you. Basically, continuity means that $f(\text{limit}) = \text{limit}(f)$ (i.e. the operations $f$ and $\lim$ can be interchanged), since $a$ is equal to $\lim_k x_k.$

Comment: Error fixed. It was simply a typo and not the source of my confusion.

Comment: \lim_{k\to\infty}

Answer (score 0):

It says: if the sequence $x_n$ gets arbitrarily close to $x$ and stays arbitrarily close to it- in other words, then $f(x_n)$ gets arbitrarily close to $f(x)$ (and stays there). Which is what the $\varepsilon-\delta$-definition says, too, really, but using distance measurements instead of convergence. It's the whole idea of continuity: if the inputs of a function get close, then so do the outputs.